# Save pdf file from api response body - pdf saved as blank file

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, automation, pdf-generation

I'm doing api automation using nodejs v15 wherein I get a buffer as response body which I need to save as a PDF file in local. I'm able to create a pdf file with name 'pdf123.pdf' with 8kb and 2 pages which is expected. I have 2 prob statements
Issue 1 - When I open the pdf file saved, it shows 2 blank pages. The content is missing. I have tried encoding = null and "binary" as well. Didn't work as expected. (Code as below)

API response.body looks like below
"%PDF-1.4\n%����\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Catalog\n/Version /1.5\n/Pages 2.....

```
let request = require('request-promise');
    var api = "/report/download/request1";
    var auth = "Basic ####";

    var args = {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/pdf",
            "Authorization": auth,
        },
        encoding: "binary"
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return webApi.restCall(api, "GET", args.data, args.headers).then((response) => {
            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('pdf123.pdf');
            writeStream.write(response.body, 'binary');
            writeStream.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('wrote all data to file');
            });
            writeStream.end();
            resolve("Resolved")
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject("API call failed");
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, except I needed the PDF to open in a new browser tab. I saw the same behavior - it would open a new tab as a PDF with the correct number of pages, but all pages were blank. I finally got it working, and then I adjusted my code for your use case. Note that I'm using axios, but AFAIK there shouldn't be any difference in the result.

```
function getPDFandWriteToFile() {

  var api = "/report/download/request1";
  var auth = "Basic ####";

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: api,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': auth, 
    },    
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios(config)
    .then((response) => {
      let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('pdf123.pdf')
      writeStream.once('open', (fd) =>{
        writeStream.write(new Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'))
        writeStream.on('finish', () => {
          console.log('wrote all data to file');
        });
        writeStream.end()
      })
      resolve(response);
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error)
      }
    );
  });  
}
```